# References is not showing up - Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, natbib, cite-package

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4 paper,title page,]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5in, 8.5in}]{geometry}    
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./Images/} }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2009}{\,} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\section{Method}

In the first part of the study, I'll discuss the different Hubble constant measurement techniques...\cite{Riess2009}.



\bibliography{References}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}


\end{document}
```

When I do this it prints

**[1] Adam G. Riess et al. A Redetermination of the Hubble Constant with the Hubble Space
Telescope from a Differential Distance Ladder. Astrophys. J., 699:539–563, 2009.**

and my reference looks like

```
@article{Riess2009,
    author = "Riess, Adam G. and others",
    title = "{A Redetermination of the Hubble Constant with the Hubble Space Telescope from a Differential Distance Ladder}",
    eprint = "0905.0695",
    archivePrefix = "arXiv",
    primaryClass = "astro-ph.CO",
    doi = "10.1088/0004-637X/699/1/539",
    journal = "Astrophys. J.",
    volume = "699",
    pages = "539--563",
    year = "2009"
}
```

As you can see

```
eprint = "0905.0695"
archivePrefix = "arXiv"
primaryClass = "astro-ph.CO"
```

are missing in the reference. How can I make them appear in the reference. Also Is there way to connect this with a link such that when I click this reference it will directly send me to the https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0695

Thanks

Comment: Which document class do you employ?

Comment: @Mico I edit my post now

Comment: The bibtex style you use will only know certain data types for each category, certain will be mandatory, some optional, the rest are ignored completely. This is normal. For this style if you want a link added to it you're better of adding it manually to the optional note field forfattee via the `\url` command. Either this or find a better bibtex style or switch to biblatex entirely

Comment: @daleif how can I fix it

Comment: See my updated comment. In short : you cannot

Comment: @daleif I see . I am an undergrad so I am completely new to this stuff any ideas what kind of style I can use ? You can also share link

Comment: No idea. Many of the styles for bibtex was made before arxiv was even a thing. If this is just for a thesis then look at biblatex (it is a package, and it uses biber, not bibtex). If you're writing a paper for a journal biblatex is not recommended as most journals don't support it. Biblatex can do and supports much more than plain bibtex

Comment: @daleif I am using Texmaker. Yes its just a project. I am not going to send to a journal.

Comment: Texmakers only relevans here is that you'll need to reconfigure it a bit if you switch to biblatex as it needs to run biber and not bibtex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before getting to the heart of your question, let me point out that the BibTeX source data you've obtained -- presumably from some online repository -- is a curious mixture of what would be appropriate for an entry of type `@article` on the one hand and an entry of type `@misc` on the other. To wit, if one goes to https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0695 and clicks on the "Export citation" link on the right-hand side of the window, one can choose between two entirely different citation data formats. One is the published journal article form, viz.,

```
@article{Riess_2009,
   title={A REDETERMINATION OF THE HUBBLE CONSTANT WITH THE HUBBLE SPACE TELESCOPE FROM A DIFFERENTIAL DISTANCE LADDER},
   volume={699},
   ISSN={1538-4357},
   url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0004-637X/699/1/539},
   DOI={10.1088/0004-637x/699/1/539},
   number={1},
   journal={The Astrophysical Journal},
   publisher={IOP Publishing},
   author={Riess, Adam G. and Macri, Lucas and Casertano, Stefano and Sosey, Megan and Lampeitl, Hubert and Ferguson, Henry C. and Filippenko, Alexei V. and Jha, Saurabh W. and Li, Weidong and Chornock, Ryan and Sarkar, Devdeep},
   year={2009},
   month={Jun},
   pages={539–563}
}
```

The other is the Arxiv eprint form, viz.,

```
@misc{riess2009redetermination,
    title={A Redetermination of the Hubble Constant with the Hubble Space Telescope from a Differential Distance Ladder},
    author={Adam G. Riess and Lucas Macri and Stefano Casertano and Megan Sosey and Hubert Lampeitl and Henry C. Ferguson and Alexei V. Filippenko and Saurabh W. Jha and Weidong Li and Ryan Chornock and Devdeep Sarkar},
    year={2009},
    eprint={0905.0695},
    archivePrefix={arXiv},
    primaryClass={astro-ph.CO}
}
```

I believe you should choose one or the other publication format -- but *not* a hybrid of the two.

Let's stick with the `@article` version but also (a) fix the odd-ball uppercasing of the `title` field and (b) truncate the list of authors as per what you showed in your posting:

```
@article{Riess_2009,
    title={{A Redetermination of the Hubble Constant with the 
       Hubble Space Telescope from a Differential Distance Ladder}},
   volume={699},
   ISSN={1538-4357},
   url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0004-637X/699/1/539},
   DOI={10.1088/0004-637x/699/1/539},
   number={1},
   journal={The Astrophysical Journal},
   publisher={IOP Publishing},
   author={Riess, Adam G. and others},
   year={2009},
   month={Jun},
   pages={539-563}
}
```

Observe that this entry features fields named `doi`, `url`, and `issn`.

Aside: It's important to be aware of the fact that the `unsrt` bibliography style has been around in essentially unchanged form since the mid-1980s [!]. Back then, the Internet was but a gleam in the eye of Tim Berners-Lee, and nobody had yet conceived the idea of storing publications in electronic form at (electronic) locations identified by their URLs. Maybe unsurprisingly, then, the `unsrt` bibliography style has not been programmed to recognonize fields such as `doi` and `url`; unrecognized fields are simply ignored.

What to do, then? I suggest you switch from using the `cite` citation management package and the `unsrt` bibliography style to the `natbib` citation management package and the `unsrtnat` bibliography style. You should also load the `url` (or, better yet, the `xurl`) package -- as well as the `hyperref` package if you want the URL strings to be clickable hyperlinks.

[image]

Observe that the contents of the `issn`, `doi`, and `url` fields are all shown. That's presumably way too much information; you might decide to delete the `issn` and `doi` fields.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5in, 8.5in}]{geometry} 

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{References.bib}
@article{Riess_2009,
    title={{A Redetermination of the Hubble Constant with the 
       Hubble Space Telescope from a Differential Distance Ladder}},
   volume={699},
   ISSN={1538-4357},
   url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0004-637X/699/1/539},
   DOI={10.1088/0004-637x/699/1/539},
   number={1},
   journal={The Astrophysical Journal},
   publisher={IOP Publishing},
   author={Riess, Adam G. and others},
   year={2009},
   month={Jun},
   pages={539-563}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{Riess_2009}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfectly well.